# How should my customer authorize my server-side application to access their Azure resources?

Tags: azure, azure-security

We've built an application that reads information about a customer's cloud resources and gives them insights.  It's currently implemented for AWS.

In AWS, I have my customer create an IAM role with a Trust policy and External ID, and share that information with me.  I then "Assume Role" into their account.  What is the equivalent approach in Azure?

I see concepts like "Application", "Service Principal", etc - but everything I read seems super-focused on SSO and authorizing corporate users to "access external apps" rather than authorizing server-side applications themselves.

Am I supposed to create an "application" and have them add it?  Do I create a user and have them invite it?  Sorry - I'm fairly new to Azure, and most of the documentation so far treats me like an IT administrator trying to add Jira to a IdP portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can either have them do it all and give you the credentials or build an app that allows them to setup everything in a semi-automatically.

The manual option requires them to create an app registration, which generates a service principal, and then grant RBAC roles to the service principal. Then they can give you the tenant id, client id and secret. Instead of a secret you can also create a certificate and give them the public key. They can add it as a credential to the app.

There's command-line tools they can use to generate the SP and app too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create-for-rbac

The semi-automatic option is that you build an app that is registered in your AAD tenant as a multi-tenant app and requires access to Azure Resource Management API as the currently signed-in user. 
They can then login, you can get a list of their subscriptions, they can choose one, and you can do the analysis right there and then.
You can store a refresh token to keep access over a longer time as well.

Comment: Thanks!  If my app has no interactivity with a user (e.g., runs daily, automatically), is it fair to say the RBAC credentials are the best approach?

Comment: I would say it'll be easier. Though the interactivity would be required only once, refresh tokens can and do expire. In those cases you'd need them to interact again to get new tokens. That problem doesn't exist with the first approach where they register the app. Though the secret / certificate can of course expire. It's also more manual work.